# Continuous serial write in win32 , C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, serial-port

I need to perform continous serial write on the serial port till the application is running . Can anyone suggest what is the appropriate step to continously write data in regular time interval in serial communication using win32 .

I have done port open, write, read and close on button click . It means that if i click open button then it opens the port, write button to write, read button to read and close button to close the port. I have used file operation technique on serial port on win32 platform. The steps can be summarised as

1. open port (createfile)
2. check port exist or not
3. set serial parameters
4. set timeouts
5. write data (writefile)
6. read data (readfile)
7. close port

I have done this to learn about serial communication . but actually i have to write the data continuously until the application is running and at the same time read the data as it becomes available in the serial port. I have not implemented threading concept in my program . Threading is a new topic for me and if i have to use it to obtain my objective, please suggest an appropriate step. My objectives are

1. write the data continuously till the application is running.
2. The continuous data should be written at certain time interval . (is there any timer concept in c++).
3. Read the data from serial port whenever data is available at the port.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: "write on the serial port till the application is running" Do you mean "until the application stops running"?  Or is "the application" not referring to this bit of software you're trying to write?

Comment: Perform step 5 and 6 in a loop?

Comment: I am referring to the application that is trying to write. Once the application is launched it have to start writing and when it is closed the writing should be stopped. How can we put step 5 and 6 in loop.

Comment: Will you be reusing the write data, or write data can change? If former, you can just do it in the main thread and loop as long as you want. If latter, then you can do the data change in the main thread then do the serial write in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do Windows API serial reads and writes concurrently it is necessary to have a read thread and a write thread. And if you are doing this in a GUI program then these threads should be separate from the main GUI thread.

This MSDN article describes the details and mentions a sample code named MTTTY that combines read, write and GUI. Unfortunately, MTTTY does not seem to be available any more on MSDN. Maybe you can find it if you have access to old MSDN library disks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx

Comment: yea actually i have seen this page before but i cannot download the sample code MTTTY so if anyone can give the downloadable link or share this sample code then it will be really a great help for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
stopSignal=CreateEvent(stuff);  //signal this with SetEvent() to stop the serial thread. 
..
CreateThread(blah,SerialThreadProc,blah);
..
void* SerialThreadProc(){
    open port (createfile);
    check port exist or not;
    set serial parameters;
    set timeouts;
    do{
      write data (writefile);
      read data (readfile);
    }while(WAIT_TIMEOUT==WaitForSingleObject(stopSignal,commsInterval));//expect yoda flame
    close port
};
```

Comment: Can i ask you is it single thread or multiple thread that i need to implement in my code. actually i am looking for threading in the google and i am not quite clear about what kind of threading i need in my program